# SQL Server Import Export _ Destination Not Showing

Tags: sql-server

I have created a new database in SQL Server Management Studio. I am trying to import data from an Excel file into the new database.

When using the Import/Export wizard, for destination I first select SQL Server Native Client 11.0. However, the new database I created does not show up in the database dropdown list, only the default system databases are shown as options (i.e. master, model, msdb, tempdb).

How do I get the wizard to find the new database I created ?

Comment: does the import user has the access to the new database ?

Comment: I assume so, this is just my own desktop version, i'm the only user.